# How can I get random row fetched from SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking to get data from SQL Server randomly and present it in a view. I am able to get the data using `OrderBy(Guid.NewGuid())`.

But I do not want the user to reload and get to another record without taking any action on the previous record which was open in view. Here is the action method I created.

```
public ActionResult Feedback()
{
        var mostRecentMonday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);

        var weekEnd = mostRecentMonday.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1); //will return the end of the day on Sunday
        //int id;

        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            var uName = User.Identity.Name;               
            //int total = db.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatCreateDateTime >= mostRecentMonday && x.ChatCreateDateTime <= weekEnd && x.Feedback == null).ToArray().ToList().Count();

            var result = db.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatCreateDateTime >= mostRecentMonday && x.ChatCreateDateTime <= weekEnd && x.Feedback == null && x.Username != uName).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
            result.Scenarios = new SelectList(db.Scenarios.ToList(), "ScenarioId", "ScenarioList");

            return View(result);                      
        }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `I do not want the user to reload and get to another record without taking any action on the previous record which was open in view.` Can you clarify more about the requirement?

Comment: Above code returns a chat entered which opens in a form. Form needs to be filled by Auditor, but refreshing form re generates another chat from dB. So, I want if auditor refreshes form it should not bypass unless auditor submits form